# Where can I see beatifully formated online man pages?

Tags: manpage

I find the terminal man pages hard to read. I tried some online versions, but all cases I've seen are also hard to read because of poor formatting. Do you know where can I read modern, beautifully formatted, online man pages?

Comment: Do you just mean man pages for Ubuntu ?

Comment: @markkirby yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu has its very own, very nice, formatted man pages repository, you can [find them here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)

If you click `Install the search engine plugin for your browser` you can search them right from your browser search box.

[image]